# How can I add my developer account to Xcode from a script?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I want to use

```
xcodebuild […] -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

To build my iOS app and have a provisioning profile automatically generated.

`man xcodebuild` says:

> Requires a developer account to have been added in Xcode's Accounts preference pane.

This works fine locally. When I run this in my CI server, I see

> Code Signing Error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode

Because, of course, I'm not logged in there.

---

How can I add my developer account to Xcode from a script?

For reference, I'm using CircleCI and fastlane, but would accept any answer that uses only command-line tools.

Comment: [This answer for grabbing it from the keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47076629) seemed promising, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach, or exactly how to do it.

Comment: Similar investigation I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787309/how-to-sign-in-to-apple-id-in-xcode-via-command-line

Comment: LOL, always a step ahead of me @janpio

Comment: @AaronBrager did you get the solution for this using CLT?

Comment: @AaronBrager were you able to automate it via script?

Comment: No, it’s impossible

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to copy the .provisionprofile files to the build server, and copy to them to the right directory during the build process. You still need to log into Apple Developer - I use `-authenticationKeyID` and `-authenticationKeyIssuerID` - but no other changes are needed. The project still uses automatic signing.

It's not ideal, because the build starts to fail when the profiles expire, but  its' better than using manual signing.